# TopK function over Distributed Engine In clickhouse returns only 10 records

Tags: olap, clickhouse

I'm running the following query 
`select topK(30)(Country) from distributed_table`

note: distributed_table's engine is Distributed.

and even though there are over 100 possible "country" values, the query returns only 10.

Also, when I run it on local table , I'm getting more than 10 results.

Have I missed out some crucial configuration?

Comment: I think it's a bug https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8546

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem occurs when intermediate results from shards are combined to the final result.

Let's check the results from each shard (will use [distributed_group_by_no_merge](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/332)-setting to disable the merging of intermediate results from each shard):

```sql
select any(_shard_num), topK(30)(Country) 
from distributed_table
SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1
```

On each shard, the *topK*-function works correctly so as a workaround you can combine all intermediate results manually:

```sql
SELECT arrayDistinct(
  arrayMap(x -> x.1, 
    /* sort values by frequency */
    arraySort(x -> x.2, 
      /* converts an array of arrays to a flat array */
      flatten(
        /* group results from shards to one array */
        groupArray(
          /* assign each value the index number */
          arrayMap((x, index) -> (x, index), shard_result, arrayEnumerate(shard_result))))))) ordered_value
FROM (
  select topK(30)(Country) AS shard_result
  from distributed_table
  SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1)
```